# download youtube video offline swift

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, swift4

I'm trying to download a youtube video on the phone so the user can later play it offline. I hooked a button to where the user can download. The code of how I'm currently downloading the video is here below.

```
@objc func downloadSelectedVideo() {
        if let audioUrl = URL(string: "http://freetone.org/ring/stan/iPhone_5-Alarm.mp3") {
            // create your document folder url
            let documentsUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            // your destination file url
            let destination = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
            print(destination)
            // check if it exists before downloading it
            if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: destination.path) {
                print("The file already exists at path")
            } else {
                //  if the file doesn't exist
                //  just download the data from your url
                URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: audioUrl, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) in
                    // after downloading your data you need to save it to your destination url
                    guard
                        let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                        let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("audio"),
                        let location = location, error == nil
                        else { return }
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destination)
                        print("file saved")
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }).resume()
            }
        }
    }
```

as you can see I have hooked up the URL to a free music which is in mp3 and it works fine I can download the music and everything works just fine, however when I try to hook up a YouTube video then it never gets to the print statement file saved I tried this as the URL `if let audioUrl = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WSgJCYIewM")`

but the print statement file saved never ran, but when I tried with the other I mentioned earlier it print file saved.

What URL should use to download the youtube videos, and do I have to use an mp3 or mp4 source to download the videos. I'm trying not to use any third-party sites if you can come up with any solution it would be great and helpful. Thanks

Comment: I don't know swift, but I do know that the url for the audio is hidden in a ton of javascript, so you will need to pase that and get the nessesary components to join the url.  You are better off using a library

Comment: YouTube has an Objective-C SDK for playing videos, but downloading them or otherwise accessing them is against their terms of service

Comment: Pretty sure that even *if* you can download the video, AND Apple approves your app, that Google's lawyers would like to have a word with you.

Comment: it's very weird because there an app called music FM that i download directly from the app store and the app is based on that you can listen to music offline from souces like youtube, spotify. However thanks for answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YouTube spells this out pretty specifically that you cannot do this.

[YouTube API Services - Developer Policies](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies)

Found this under **E. Handling YouTube Data and Content**

> You and your API Clients must not, and must not encourage, enable, or
>   require others to:
>
> download, import, backup, cache, or store copies of YouTube
>   audiovisual content without YouTube's prior written approval,

IANAL, but I'd rather not go up against their legal team.

Comment: yeah your right will ditch the idea of downloading music illegally

Answer (score 3):

YouTube does not provide a simple URL that taps into the video or audio directly. Instead, you would have to extract thier link using some algorithm. If you'd like to achieve that I would recommend you use [XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) as it is well maintained and easy to use. However, If you'd like a ready made app, I have developed an open source application - [YouTag](https://github.com/youstanzr/YouTag) - that you can simply install on your iOS device and use directly without having to go through developing one.